# Can multiple websites/domains be hosted by the same Platform as a Service [PAAS]?

Tags: wordpress, apache, cloud-hosting, tomcat, paas

Sorry if this is trivial, but I am still learning the basics of PAAS, so I appreciate your patience...

1. **Can separate websites both be hosted by a single PAAS (used via single account with a given popular PAAS-provider)?**

I think they can, but I'm not certain, and want to make sure...

In particular, I want to host both a Wordpress blog (whose PHP needs Apache) & a Java WAR webApp (with servlets needing Tomcat); each served for different domains.  So these would be independent websites.

2. *I think if yes to 1., hosting separate sites with 1 PAAS is possible, and Tomcat & Apache are both in its stack, then I can host the particulars I mentioned with the single PAAS?*

I was initially planning to do all of this with a traditional web hosting provider, but have realized I can probably achieve the same with a PAAS for cheaper & simpler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but be aware that Tomcat and Apache would have to be accessed over different port so if someone wanted to access the Tomcat app they would have to access it using the Tomcat port which is port 8080 by default. If you don't want to have the port at the end of the domain (as http is port 80) then you would need to run two separate servers one for Apache on port 80 and the other with Tomcat on port 80 and have them as two separate fully qualified domain names.